# Create a room use incremental time slot dataframe using R

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm trying to create a heatmap dataframe for room use.

| id | room | day | start | finish |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ROOM A | Mon | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 |
| 2 | ROOM A | Tue | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
| 3 | ROOM A | Mon | 10:00:00 | 14:30:00 |
| 4 | ROOM B | Wed | 09:00:00 | 11:00:00 |

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:4),
room = c("room a", "room a", "room a", "room b"),
day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Mon", "Wed"),
start = c("09:00", "09:00", "10:00", "09:00"),
end = c("11:00", "10:00", "14:30", "11:00"))
```

into a dataframe that I can turn into a heatmap such as:

| room | day | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROOM A | Mon | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM A | Tue | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM A | Wed | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM A | Thu | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM A | Fri | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM B | Mon | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM B | Tue | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM B | Wed | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM B | Thu | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ROOM B | Fri | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

The hour windows should increment for every booking in that slot (or half hour which counts as the full hour being used). Its for around 2000 bookings of around 50 rooms.

I've tried a godawful nested loop of cycling through every event ID, day of the week, timeslot but had no joy (and I'm too embarrased to enter the code here!). I suspect vectorised functions might win the day if anyone has the time? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The toy data mimics the real data, i.e. no date variables? Just day of week for a single week?

Comment: There are multiple weeks in play but I'm not worried about the weeks/dates as such. Thats why each time slot should increment for each time it is used if this makes sense. Hence why ROOM A, 10 is a "2" as that slot is in use twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected result for room B on Wednesday is not consistent with the rest (where the intervals are right-open).

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:4),
                 room = c("room a", "room a", "room a", "room b"),
                 day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Mon", "Wed"),
                 start = c("09:00", "09:00", "10:00", "09:00"),
                 end = c("11:00", "10:00", "14:30", "11:00"))
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
library(chron)
df[, c("start", "end") := .(times(paste0(start,":00")), times(paste0(end,":00")))]

schedule <- CJ(day = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"), 
               time = times("09:00:00") + (0:8)/24,
               room = c("room a", "room b"))

occ <- df[schedule, .(day = i.day, room = i.room, time = i.time, id), 
          on = c("day==day", "room==room","start<=time", "end>time")]
occ <- occ[, sum(!is.na(id)), by = .(room, day, time)]
occ[, time := floor(time * 24)]
occ[, day := factor(day, c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"), ordered = TRUE)]

dcast(occ, room + day ~ time)
#      room day  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
# 1: room a Mon  1  2  1  1  1  1  0  0  0
# 2: room a Tue  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 3: room a Wed  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 4: room a Thu  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 5: room a Fri  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 6: room b Mon  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 7: room b Tue  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 8: room b Wed  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# 9: room b Thu  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#10: room b Fri  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the heads up on the error - I have changed the Wednesday data. Thanks also for the solution!